# flutter build_runner: Build for specific file extensions in build.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart, code-generation, build-runner

I want to speed up the build time that build_runner takes, and I also want to prevent a re-build when running `build watch` when I am editing files that don't have any files to generate.

I know that this needs to be edited in the `build.yaml` file, but I can't get anything to work.

this is my build file

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      auto_route_generator:
        generate_for: 
          include: [".route.dart"]
      freezed:
        generate_for: 
          include: [".model.dart"]
      json_serializable:
        generate_for:
          include: [".model.dart"]
        options:
          explicit_to_json: true
          include_if_null: false
```

Even trying to add `enabled: false`, which makes me believe that it would disable the build for that dependency, does nothing and the files continue to be generated.

Maybe I am just misunderstanding how the build file is supposed to be used...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution. It is very close igokom's answer.

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      auto_route_generator|autoRouteGenerator:
        enabled: true
        generate_for:
          include:
            - lib/infrastructure/routes/app_routes.routes.dart
          # [exclude] is not needed if at least one path is provided
          # in [include]. It will only target [include]d paths
          # exclude:
          #   - ...

      json_serializable:
        enabled: true
        generate_for:
          include:
            - lib/**.model.dart
            - lib/**_bloc.dart
            - lib/**_cubit.dart

        options:
          explicit_to_json: true
          include_if_null: false
      freezed|freezed:
        enabled: true
        generate_for:
          include:
            - lib/**.model.dart
            - lib/**_bloc.dart
            - lib/**_cubit.dart

      injectable_generator|injectable_builder:
        enabled: true
        generate_for:
          include:
            - lib/**_bloc.dart
            - lib/**_cubit.dart
            - lib/**.dao.dart

      injectable_generator|injectable_config_builder:
        enabled: true
        generate_for:
          include:
            - lib/infrastructure/injection/injection.dart
```

I was getting a Warning previously which read
`[WARNING] Configuring 'auto_route_generator:auto_route_generator' in target 'my_app:my_app' but this is not a known Builder`

I was getting this error because the name of the generator for `auto_route` is not `auto_route_generator`, rather `autoRouteGenerator`.

These values can be found within the plugins `build.yaml` file

```yaml
builders:
  # [autoRouteGenerator] is the name of the generator
  # that needs to be referenced
  autoRouteGenerator:
    import: "package:auto_route_generator/builder.dart"
    builder_factories: ["autoRouteGenerator"]
    build_extensions: {'.dart': ['.gr.dart']}
    auto_apply: dependents
    build_to: source
```

> Targets can be referred to in '$definingPackageName:$targetname'. When the target name matches the package name it can also be referred to as just the package name. One target in every package must use the package name so that consumers will use it by default. In the build.yaml file this target can be defined with the key $default or with the name of the package.

[You can find more info about it here](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/build_config/README.md) and [this is a pretty good article](https://www.wilsonwilson.dev/articles/flutter-build-yaml/) that gives some good tips for the `build.yaml` file

---

#### For those using `v6` for `auto_route_library`

Use `auto_route_generator|autoRouteBuilder` and `auto_route_generator|autoRouterBuilder`

Can refer to [v6-build.yaml](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/blob/v6.0.0_redesigned/auto_route_generator/build.yaml)

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow syntax and check this one:

```yaml
    targets:
      $default:
        builders:
          # also be sure, that builder name is correct
          # i guess it has pattern like this X:X:
          # in my case json_serializable:json_serializable:
          auto_route_generator:auto_route_generator:
            generate_for:
              include:
                - lib/**.route.dart
                # or full path to file here
    #... and so on
```

Comment: I get a warning that states `[WARNING] Configuring 'auto_route_generator:auto_route_generator' in target 'my_app:my_app' but this is not a known Builder`. Will it still work with this warning?